# Any subgroup $H$ of $G$ contains a normal subgroup of $G$ that contains all normal subgroups of $G$ contained in $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

As in the title, I need to prove the following statement: Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup. Then $H$ contains a normal subgroup of $G$, say $N$, such that all normal subgroups of $G$ that are contained in $H$ are also contained in $N$.

My thought is to take the union $R$ of all the normal subgroups of $G$ that are contained in $H$, and let $N$ be the normal subgroup of $G$ generated by $R$, and then prove that $N$ is contained in $H$. But I do not know how to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/64152/591889

Comment: Also look at [this](https://wiki.ubc.ca/images/7/71/Problems.pdf) for full solution.

Comment: More simply, one can take the intersection of the conjugates of $H$. This is called the normal core of $H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{N_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ be the family of all normal subgroups of $G$ contained in $H$. The family is nonempty, since $1\subseteq H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. I claim $N:=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}N_\lambda$, the group generated by all the $N_\lambda$'s, satisfied the conditions given. First, since $N_\lambda\subseteq H$ for each $\lambda\in\Lambda$, clearly we also have $N\subseteq H$. Moreover, every normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$ is one of the $N_\lambda$, which is by definition contained in $N$.

Thus, all that is left to show is that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. But this is clear, since an element of $N$ is of the form $h_1h_2\dots h_n$, where $h_n\in N_{\lambda_n}$, and so for each $g\in G$, we have $g(h_1h_2\dots h_n)g^{-1}=(gh_1g^{-1})(gh_2g^{-1})\dots(gh_ng^{-1})\in N$. (This argument also shows uniqueness.)

---

Alternatively, you can just let $N=\bigcap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}$, which is easily checked to satisfy all the necessary properties.

Comment: Thank you, and I can see that this $N$ is the same as I mentioned in the post.